# Azure Data Factory For Each Loop is importing all my CSV files per iteration instead of just the file name I *think* I've told it to

Tags: azure-data-factory

I could really do with some help with ADF; I've recently started trying to use it thinking it would be similar to SSIS but wow am I having a hard time! I've built up this kinda complicated pipeline over the last few weeks which basically reads a list of files from a folder and from within a For Each loop it's supposed to check where the data starts per file and import it into a SQL table. I'll not bore you with all the issues I've had so far but atm it seems to be working aside from the For Each part of it, it's importing all the files in the folder per iteration and it seems to be the data set configuration which is not recognising the filename per iteration because if I look through the debugging I can see it pick up the list of files, set the DSFileName variable to the first of them, but the output of the data flow task is both files. So it seems like I've missed a step somewhere and I've just spent the last 5 hours looking and could really do with some help :(

I reckon to have followed the instructions here: https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-use-iterations-and-conditions-activities-in-azure-data-factory/

Some pictures to show the debugging I've done:

[Here it shows it's picking up 2 files (after I filtered out folders and stuff)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lumf.jpg)

[Here shows the first file name only being passed into the first data flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2umZO.jpg)

[Here shows the output from it, where it has picked up both files somehow and displays the count of 2 files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fsudv.jpg)

[Here shows the Data Set set up where I believe to have correctly set the variable as the file name to be used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNc2i.jpg)

I just don't even know where to start now tbh, I reckon to have checked everything I can see and I'm not using any wild cards or anything. I can see it passing the 1 file name per iteration into that variable but each iteration I can see 2x counts of the file going into the table and the output of each data flow task showing both file counts.

Does anybody have any ideas or know what I've missed?

EDIT 23/07/22: Pics of the source as requested:
[Data Source Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QU7Vj.jpg)
[Data Source Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0H76C.jpg)

Comment: Can you show the Source configuration for the Data Flow?

Comment: The scope of variables is pipeline level, so when you use Set Variable within a parallel For Each activity it can mixed up.  Simply use the variable expression in the main activity / dataset - this might solve one issue.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that adding .name to item() in the dataset parameter means it uses just the current one instead of them all.... I'm confused by this as all the documentation I've read states that item() references the CURRENT item within the For Each, did I misunderstand?

[Adding .name to the dataset here is now importing just the current file per loop iteration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2WJv.jpg)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).